# creating numpy 2D array from list of numpy 1D array

Tags: python, numpy

I am facing an abnormal behavior of `numpy` array, while trying to create numpy 2D array from some numpy array. Below is the sample code-

```
x = []
x.append(x1)
x.append(x2)
x.append(x3)
x = np.array(x)

print x1.shape, type(x1)
print x2.shape, type(x2)
print x3.shape, type(x3)
print  x.shape, type(x)
print x[0].shape, type(x[0])

(1318,) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1352,) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1286,) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(3,) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1318,) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I wasn't expecting for this output. Hence I tired another code, which looks like below-

```
x1 = np.arange(4)
x2 = np.arange(4,8)
x3 = np.arange(8,12)
x.append(x1)
x.append(x2)
x.append(x3)
x = np.array(x)

print x.shape
(3, 4)
```

Why, I am not seeing 2d array in first case?

Comment: What shape were you hoping the first array to be? The length of each component is not equal.

Comment: wtf!!! I got it. I need to resample all the data first....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length of each array were equal, you would indeed see the 2d shape you were expecting - as you mentioned in a comment you should resample accordingly.

---

Your currently constructed "jagged array" of arrays would have to be treated similarly to a regular Python list, and does not support nice things like `.sum()`.

*With a similarly jagged array*

```
>>> x.sum()
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3,)
```

This lack of support for jagged arrays is because NumPy is optimized for arrays of numbers with a fixed dimension.